# Joomla - Overlapping of modules required

Tags: module, joomla, joomla1.5

I had to create a custom menu for the template we chose as the links were supposed to be added over a image. I have a header image which is called in as a module. When I select mod_mainmenu, the menu shows over the header image. However when I disable the mod_mainmenu and select the custom html mod , they come below the header image.

I need it also to come as the menu. Which will resolve the issue.

www.diaryboard.com/ship

This is the link. Could someone help me on this.

Regards
Edward

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see is in your template.css file on line 672 -

```
height: 448pxx;
```

Fix this typo first. You could probably do without the absolute positioning for the logo, but the typo will probably make the page look right.